# PayPal fetchDeviceReferenceTokenWithAppID returns empty

Tags: ios, paypal

To Integrate PayPal MECL, I did below steps.

1. Added Library. I added MECL Library(libPayPalEC.a, PayPal.h), libxml2.dylib into the project.
2. Implemented DeviceReferenceTokenDelegate and added delegate methods.
3. Called below method by a button tapped.

   [[PayPal getPayPalInst] fetchDeviceReferenceTokenWithAppID:@"APP-80W284485P519543T" forEnvironment:ENV_SANDBOX withDelegate:self];
4. Then called method by delegate 'receivedDeviceReferenceToken:'

Problem is in step 4. Received token is always empty.

I just followed manual and that's all.

Did I something wrong?

Comment: I decide to share zip: https://www.dropbox.com/s/skzzq2te6wjqfqk/PayPal_iOS_Lib.zip. Just for reference.
I recommend we should not use this library for release, it'll be replaced soon according to the note: https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/integration/mobile/ios-integration-guide/